# TCP-IP client-server application to manipulate a dictionary

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am writing a Client-server program.

The Server would hold a dictionary, and clients are able to add an update key-values to the dictionary.

Suppose a client-**'A'** adds an item `(1, 111)`. When another client-**'B'** wants to update the value of `(1, 111)`, it has to seek a confirmation from **'A'**, and vice versa.

---

Kindly, take a look at the following program:

```
using MyClientServerLib;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyServerProgram
{
    class ServerProgram
    {
        static Dictionary<string, KeyValue> KeyValueDictionary;
        static Dictionary<string, ClientClass> ClientDictionary;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            Console.WriteLine("Server program started...");

            KeyValueDictionary = new Dictionary<string, KeyValue>();
            ClientDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ClientClass>();

            string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            int portNo = 2000;

            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);            
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, portNo);            

            // poll for clients in a 2nd thread
            Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                ServerProgram.PollIncomingClientConns(listener);
            });

            thread.Start();
        }

        #region catching client connections
        static void PollIncomingClientConns(TcpListener listener)
        {
            listener.Start();

            try
            {
                bool keepRunning = true;

                while (keepRunning)
                {
                    ClientClass client = new ClientClass(listener);

                    ClientDictionary.Add(client.ID, client);

                    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
                    {
                        ServerProgram.ReadFromClient(client);
                    });
                    thread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var inner = ex.InnerException as SocketException;
                if (inner != null && inner.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                listener.Stop();
            }
        } 
        #endregion

        static void ReadFromClient(ClientClass client)
        {
           try
            {
                ClientClass origClient = null; 

                while (client.Tcp.Connected)
                {
                    string str = client.ReadString();

                    switch(str)
                    {
                        case Commands.AddKeyValue:
                            string key = client.ReadString();
                            string val = client.ReadString();
                            KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(client.ID, key, val);
                            KeyValueDictionary.Add(key, keyValue);
                            Console.WriteLine(keyValue.ToString() + " added.");
                            break;

                        case Commands.ListKeys:
                            if (KeyValueDictionary.Keys.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (string key1 in KeyValueDictionary.Keys)
                                {
                                    client.Write("(" + key1 + "," + KeyValueDictionary[key1].Value + ")\t");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                client.Write("No KV");
                            }
                            break;

                        case Commands.UpdateValue: //obtain update requester client-ID                            
                            client.Key = client.ReadString(); //read key 
                            client.Value = client.ReadString(); //read val

                            KeyValue oldKeyVal = null;

                            bool currClientFound = KeyValueDictionary.TryGetValue(client.Key, out oldKeyVal); //search the dictionary with the client name

                            if (currClientFound) //if found
                            {
                                if (oldKeyVal.ClientID.Equals(client.ID))//if rem requested by same client...
                                {
                                    KeyValueDictionary[client.Key].Value = client.Value;
                                    client.Write(client.Key + " is updated.");
                                }
                                else //if rem requested by a different client...
                                {
                                    //get the original client                                                                        
                                    bool origClientFound = ClientDictionary.TryGetValue(oldKeyVal.ClientID, out origClient); //search the dictionary with the client name

                                    if (origClientFound)
                                    {
                                        origClient.Write(client.ID + " wants to change " + oldKeyVal.ToString() + "(y/n)");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case Commands.Yes:
                            Console.WriteLine(client.Key + ", " + client.Value);
                            KeyValueDictionary[client.Key].Value = client.Value;
                            client.Write(client.Key + " is updated.");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                client.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in `case Commands.UpdateValue` and `case Commands.Yes`.

When a client requests for an update in previous iteration, the key-value pair is saved with the client-instance. Then, in the next iteration, when the other client sends an affirmation, the key-value pair is updated.

But, in the next iteration, `client.Key` is showing `null`. Hence `case Commands.Yes` is failing.

How can I solve this issue?

---

Additional source code files:

1. [ClientProgram.cs](https://pastebin.com/9jiqRbh9)
2. [ClientClass.cs](https://pastebin.com/aBnFY7L7)

Comment: The Dictionary class is not thread safe, if you have two clients writing to the dictionary at the same time you will break the class and it will start to throw errors and give incorrect results. Either switch to a ConcurrentDictionary or you will need to add locking around your reads and writes to keep the class from breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by making key and value holding variables static:

```
 class ServerProgram
 { 
      static stKey;
      static stValue;

      ....
      ....      
                    case Commands.UpdateValue: //obtain update requester client-ID                            
                        stKey = client.ReadString(); //read key 
                        stValue = client.ReadString(); //read val

                        ....
                        ....

                    case Commands.Yes:
                        Console.WriteLine(stKey + ", " + stValue);
                        KeyValueDictionary[stKey].Value = stValue;
                        client.Write(stKey + " is updated.");
                        break;

     }
```